# Why the default IP and port number of Apache IoTDB reported `TEndpoint` and unable to start?

Tags: database, time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I tried Version 1.1.2 and 1.1.3 of Apache IoTDB, and the DataNode is connected to the `127.0.0.1` IP and `10710` port by default, but the the IP set for the IoTDB server cannot be used and IoTDB was unable to start. The server prompted: `The current node may have been down TEndpoint(ip:127.0.0.1 port:10710), try next node`. Anyone know what reason this problem may happen?

Answer (score 0):

This IP address and port number is corresponded to the ConfigNode settings of Apache IoTDB, therefore you can check if this is the same with your configurations of the ConfigNode in IoTDB.